# How to fill NA in column with value in next column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
Type   value1                                           value2            
1    Error: unexpected                                seq warn
2    Warning message                                  excepted action 
3    NA                                               produce values
4    In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "v1")     values produced 
5    NA                                               rewriting data
```

i want to fill NAs in column value1 with value in column value2. How could i write that condition? Desired result is:

```
Type   value1                                           value2            
1    Error: unexpected                                seq warn
2    Warning message                                  excepted action 
3    produce values                                   produce values
4    In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "v1")     values produced 
5    rewriting data                                   rewriting data
```

Comment: Find the rows with NA, then assign value from other column: `df1[ is.na(df1$value1), "value1"] <-  df1[ is.na(df1$value1), "value2"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coalesce` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  mutate(value1 = coalesce(value1, value2))
```

Or in base R :

```
transform(df, value1 = ifelse(is.na(value1), value2, value2))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `fcoalesce` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, value1 := fcoalesce(value1, value2)]
```